# github, contributor list, there is no my name

Tags: github

I got a problem.
When I am committing something to github from my console, it asks me to provide my login & password. After this when I am going to my github page, I notice that in there only my name appear (without my avatar and link to my account). In the contributors list there is no my account also. I have done a lot of commits already.

What should I do to display my account instead of my name for all these commits and also to appear in commit statistic?

Answer (score 1):

Email in git config should be same as in your Github account

git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git

Try to add email with which you sent your commits from [Github settings](https://github.com/settings/emails) to make previous commits belong to your account.

Comment: Thank you.
But 'git config user.email' command showed that my email before was like: MyFirstName-MyLastName@github.com

Is it possible to access this email?

Comment: Look at this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git#comment14673827_750182

Comment: Look at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git